# dir.exists() too slow on network paths

Tags: r, windows, network-drive

I want to check if a directory exists on a windows network drive. On the case that it does not exist, the `dir.exists()` functions takes too much time to return. I understand this is due to windows API.

Is there any other way to check the existence of a directory on a network drive but faster?

Comment: What does "too slow" mean? Obviously network paths are slower than local paths, and it's entirely possible that there are some issues with the specific network adapter implementation. But, on my system at least, `dir.exists` on a network path still takes fractions of a second; and non-existent network paths are not slower (in fact, they're *faster*) than existing network paths.

Comment: Assuming you are not the sysadmin in charge of those drives: ask your sysadmins how those network drives are mounted. Are they auto-mounted, perhaps  via  Samba? Are they password-protected, and your cached credentials have expired? Did someone change the "external" settings of the folder the drive is mapped to (renamed it, changed sharing settings...)

Comment: @KonradRudolph Too slow is like 20 seconds versus less than a milisecond for a directory that exists. 
I tried this with another network and it dissapears, so it should be something with the setup of that network as knb mentioned.

Comment: @MEcon Yep, that's a bug in the specific configuration and/or driver. Incidentally, you should see the same delay if you tried navigating to a non-existent network share directory outside of R (e.g. in Windows Explorer, unless that does something quite different).